# How do I structure the `backwards` function in a Django migration without allowing null values in the database?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm implementing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469638/uuid-field-added-after-data-already-in-database-is-there-any-way-to-populate-th) to add an automatic `UUIDField` to a database with existing rows.

The suggested adjustments to the data migration are:

```
from django_extensions.utils import uuid

def forwards(self, orm):
    for item in orm['mypp.myclass'].objects.all():
        if not item.uuid:
            item.uuid = uuid.uuid4() #creates a random GUID
            item.save()


def backwards(self, orm):
    for item in orm['mypp.myclass'].objects.all():
        if item.uuid:
            item.uuid = None
            item.save()
```

However, I don't want to allow `blank=True` to my model. How would I adjust the `backwards()` function in that case? The current `item.uuid = None` would no longer work...

Comment: `blank=True` doesn't mean you cannot do this `item.uuid = None`. It is `null=True` that prevents a field from being `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the migration in 3 steps:

1. Add your `UUIDField` with `null=True` so existing rows do not break the constraint.
2. Create a data migration to fill the uuids of existing rows similar to your current code.
3. Add another migration with the NOT NULL constraint by removing the `null=True` from your field declaration.

PS: Your code is for the outdated South migrations. The current equivalent for django-migrations would be:

```
def forwards(apps, schema_editor):
    MyClass = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyClass')
    for item in MyClass.objects.all():
        # [...]
```